# How can I display what is happening in headless chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, tkinter

I want to make a program that shows what headless chrome does.
So I made a program that takes a screenshot and shows it to the user,
but it reduces too much FPS.
I tried:

```
def screen():
     global UnderShuffle   # UnderShuffle = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wrapper"]')
     global my_label   #my_label = Label(root, compound=TOP)
     UnderShuffle.screenshot("UnderShuffle.png")
     image = Image.open("UnderShuffle.png")
     photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
     my_label['image'] = photo
     my_label.photo = photo
     my_label.after(1, screen)
```

Would it be possible to show what's happening on chrome instead of screenshotting?

Comment: Attempting 1000 FPS is rather ambitious. Have you tried slowing it down?

Comment: *headless* means no GUI for the chrome, so how do you know what it is doing by capturing the screen?

Comment: You can try placing print statements in between your lines of codes to keep a track of what's going on.

Comment: @acw1668 I told it to go on one page with neverending gif. Told it to screenshot and show it to me without headless chrome, deleted screenshots and add headless and results were same